# What should I do to a get smooth navigation drawer close on navigation item click

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have used basic navigation drawer generated in android studio. I noticed my navigation slider slides off smooth and lag sometimes. I found that the lag cause  of the `LayoutInflater` I used to inflate another layout on my fragment.

What I have done is,

```
ViewGroup myLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.current_layout);
View mayLayoutTwo = LayoutInflater.from(CurrentFragment.this.getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_to_inflate, myLayout, false);
myLayout.addView(mayLayoutTwo);
```

I want to know is that possible to avoid that lag on navigation drawer slide. Help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Layout inflater called only once. not every time. Post your navigation drawer code and fragment code

Comment: No, Its a cardview. I might use that several time

Answer (score 0):

Navigation drawer with multiple fragments is common usage. So based on your fragments loading at onCreate() lifecycle stage, your Naviagtion drawer may not smooth while closing.

**So solution 1 :**
Avoid heavy loading at your fragment initiate state. (e.g loading data asynchronously.)

**Solution 2 :** 
 Display place holder view (e.g whit screen) while navigation drawer is closing. Once NV drawer is closed, show your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation for fragment transition to give the better UX, since the default one looks some kinda awkward transition so giving your own transition will make the user feel some more smoothness, and yes avoid making the larger async calls on initiating the fragment.